# increment / decrement operators precedence in PHP

Tags: php, operator-precedence

Could someone please help wrap my head around this piece of code as it does not seem to follow the precedence and associativity principles for increment/decrement operators in PHP: (This is from a comment in PHP manual increment/decrement operator page -
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

1st example -

```
$a = [ 0, 1, 2 ];
$i = 0;
$a[$i++] = $i;

var_dump( $a );
```

/* Here is the output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 1
  2 => int 2
```

And here is my interpretation of what is happening:

```
1. Array index gets calculated, so $a[$i++] is $a[0]
2. Then rval gets calculated (which after $i++ in the step above) is now 1
3. The value of the expression gets calculated which is  1.
```

So far so good.
*/

2nd example -

```
$a = [ 0, 1, 2 ];
$i = 0;
$a[$i] = $i++;

var_dump( $a );
```

/* Here is the ouput:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 0
  1 => int 0
  2 => int 2
```

And here is my interpretation of what is happening:

```
1. The array index gets calculated which should be 0 ($a[0]), but ACTUALLY it is 1 ($a[1])
2. The rval gets calculated , which is $i++ , so the value now is 0.
3. The expression value gets calculated , which should be 1 after $i++ in the step above,   but ACTUALLY it is 0.
```

So fundamentally, I am not able to understand steps 1 and 3 in the 2nd example above.
*/

Comment: your code comments are confusing.

Comment: @iputonmyrobeanwizardhat . I have added steps in each example to explain the question a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

From the same comment as your code:

> Assignment index expressions and value expressions are both evaluated before any actual assignment happens, that means that no mater where you place your post incr/decr you may not be getting the result you had in mind.

On the line `$a[$i++] = $i;`, both the index expression `$i++` on the LHS and the value expression `$i` on the RHS are being evaluated before the assignment takes place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read this text as well in the original comment. What I am looking for is to understand in a step by step manner how the values are being calculated and assigned and in what order.

Answer (score 1):

This has not so much do with the precedence of increment as it does with the precedence of the assignment operator. The left hand side of any assignment expression will be evaluated first.

In the first case above, this will select `a[0]` as the location to be assigned, increment `$i`, and then perform the assignment of `$i`, which is now `1`.